# Cookie and shopping cart explanation needed

Tags: c#, web-services, http, https, web

> Shopping basket applications today usually store the list of basket
>   contents in a database on the server side, rather than storing basket
>   items in the cookie itself. A web server typically sends a cookie
>   containing a unique session identifier. The web browser will send back
>   that session identifier with each subsequent request and shopping
>   basket items are stored associated with a unique session identifier.

Could you give me a simple example and explanation for the above quote I took from wiki ?I am sometimes confused and have a headache to read what wiki words because I am not good at English and my knowledge about webthings is not much.

Today I had a small talk, (my bad as not to be firmly knowledgeable about this), that two computers with internal IP addresses (e.g 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.11) and with the same browser will be distinguished from an authenticated web server by their session-id because the external accessed webserver can only recognize two of them as one IP address as assigned from their ISP. Is this right ? I reasoned that there were websites that could  differentiate both by their internal IPs.

I think the cookies can be used to store anything the programmer wants. Is this right ?

If only you could offer me a simple picture to tell the whole basic stuff about this. I would love it and be more more grateful.

[**UPDATE**]

Sux! Stupid me (:mad:) the guy also claimed that cookie was not used to store username but that is not correct as

> Personalization
>
> Cookies may be used to remember the information about the user who has
>   visited a website in order to show relevant content in the future. For
>   example a web server may send a cookie containing the username last
>   used to log in to a website so that it may be filled in for future
>   visits.

By the way, he is another centraler (tonguey centraler!) of my country.

Comment: Do NOT store username/password information in a cookie. Bad security.

Comment: @anAgent thanks, so the guy was right about this although he wasn't mentioning the security terminology, only "people don't store username" in the cookie

Answer (score 1):

As far as a shopping cart solution is concerned, there really isn't a right or wrong way to manage products. It comes down to what "you" want to do with the data. However, cookies are domain and browser exclusive - you cannot access a cookie that is set from a different domain or a different browser.

- Do you want to allow the user to come back to your store and access their shopping cart? Then save this in the back end.
- Do you want to expire the carts contents with the session? - Then save it with the session data or [cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Cookie.aspx) setting the expiration. ([ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Commerce Server stores a session GUID in a cookie.  That guid is associated with a users basket(s) which houses information such as selected products, billing/shipping info, credit check history, etc.

In short, you can store up to 4 KB of information in a cookie.  This is enough for rudimentary information, which is why it is normally easier to store detailed information in a database on a server.  This also allows for data mining (e.g. Customer's that bought this also browsed these items), shopping cart abandonment rates, etc.

Modern browsers allow larger storage (up to 2 GB on some) so local caching can help speed up content delivery, but that information is no longer available to the server for mining purposes.

I'm not really sure if this answers your question, or if this is an official "answer," but the comment box was too small.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The server doesn't consider external or internal IP addresses when assigning a session ID.  Even if you had two browsers on the same computer, they each show up to the server, and the server says "what's your unique ID" and each says "I don't have one".  It assigns "1" to the first one and "2" to the second one, and as those unique IDs are stored in a cookie, it never thinks about what IP each computer is coming from.

Comment: thanks I like your style of explanation, I think this is the easiest style for me to memorize :-D Man! You look like a friend of mine, man!

Answer (score 0):

> I reasoned that there were websites that could differentiate both by their internal IPs.

The web server only sees the external IP address, which will usually be the same for two computers behind a home router (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT). However the web server can also see the port number of the connection, which will be different for each computer; this *can* be used to differentiate computers behind a NAT router, however I don't think many websites use this.

---

Websites primarily use cookies for authentication. Once logged in, the cookie will store a session ID that tracks the current login session. Most other data (such as items in a shopping cart) is stored on the server for two reasons:

- Persistence: You don't want to lose all your saved data (shopping cart) because you logged out / removed the cookie.
- Size limitations: Cookies have a limited size and wouldn't be able to store everything.

---

Finally, even though the session ID itself is unique, many websites will track session ID + IP address for additional security (so that an attacker can't simply copy your session ID and use it).